# Convert any website template to work with Drupal

Tags: drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i use any static web template to work as dynamic drupal site?

Like there is a free bootstrap theme BootBusiness(http://jobpixels.com/bootbusiness/index.html) , i want to use it in my site and add Drupal CMS to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter you can read [Convert any website layout or template into a Drupal theme](https://drupal.org/node/313510) at Drupal's own docs. I'd suggest using a base theme (sometimes called a framework or starter theme) though if this is not a one shot Drupal project and you plan to use Drupal in further ones. Learning more about the Drupal's theme system and how you can extend a base theme will take more time then following step-by-step instructions blindly but in the long term, it will pay handsomely.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the below content for more information,

If you're using Drupal 5:

" xml:lang="">

**If you're using Drupal 6:**

language ?>" xml:lang="language ?>" dir="dir ?>">

**If you're using Drupal 7:**

If you are using Drupal 7, your page.tpl.php file starts after the  tag and ends before the  tag, so you do not need to worry about the doctype, html, or head tags. If you'd like to override these, copy the html.tpl.php file from your modules/system folder and make whatever changes you'd like.

This is the recommended way to start your page, rather than just using . The extra definitions here aid in proper validation and language handling of the resulting HTML markup.